# Create circular bins using x and y- coordinates

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to split my data frame into circular bins from a specific point (center of the plot) using 2 variables (x and y coordinates). The aim is to bin the data into 5 different circles starting from a point (2255, 2008) where the total matrix is (5599X4000). Can someone help me do that using R?

[image]

Comment: Please add a few rows and columns of sample data as copy/pasteable text. Also please clarify-you give 2 coordinates for a center point (2255, 2008), but if your matrix is 5599x4000, that implies 4000 dimensions, not 2.

Comment: Seems like you want to calculate the distance from the center for each out, and then bin on the distances?

Comment: `df$dist = sqrt((df$x - 2255)^2 + (df$y - 2008)^2)` then bin that, perhaps with `cut()`.

Comment: @Adam Yes that is excatly what I want to do.